# use return mediator in Mock in xunit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I need to create a Unit Test with `XUnit` and I use the mediator in my project.

I have problem with `Mock` in this test.

this is my test :

```
    [Theory, MemberData(nameof(SubscribeDataSource.GetAddSubscribe), MemberType = typeof(SubscribeDataSource))]
    public void AddSubscribe(AddSubscribeDto dto)
    {
        var model =OperationResult<string>.BuildSuccessResult("Success");

        var mock = Mock.Setup(x => x.Send(It.IsAny<CreateSubscribeCommand>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
            .Returns<OperationResult<string>>(model);

        var add = SubscribeController.AddSubscribe(dto);
    }
```

but i have error in this line `.Returns<OperationResult<string>>(model);`

it show me this error :

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State
>   Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Travel.Common.Operation.OperationResult' to 'System.Func, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>>'   Travel.XUnitTest    E:\MyProject\Trello\Travel.XUnitTest\SubscribeTest.cs   39      Active

this is `CreateSubscribeCommand` class :

```
public class CreateSubscribeCommand : AddSubscribeDto, IRequest<OperationResult<string>>
{
    public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
}
```

**What's the problem? How can I solve that problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Returns` with `ReturnsAsync`.